# NO SOUND! Resolution incorrect!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, 13.04, hdmi

I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and I can't get my sound to work or my resolution up to 1920x1080p. I am using the HDMI output.
The Nvidia X server driver isn't working and wont install.

System: Zotac Atom Ion ITX series 1.6 ghz 4 gb ram corsair force gt ssd

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)?
That should work if there is no hdmi audio option in your sound options
If you have sound but not in flash [look here](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)